# Token is null when trying to grab facebook pic

Tags: java, facebook, oauth-2.0, scribe, restfb

I used scribe to get an oauth token from facebook and passed the token in restfb. I was successfully able to achieve this. I was able to retrieve my info about me such as name, email and id. But when I tried retrieving photos, I was not successful. I observed that it returned null when I tried putting a print statement (debugging purposes) as I was not able to retrieve any info regarding the photos. Is the issue with the token, as I get a null pointer when trying to save to mongodb. I also tried printing the token but null? Need some assistance.

Below is my code:

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {


private static final String STATE = "state";
private String client_id = "***************";
private String app_secret = "**********************";
private String url = "http://localhost:8080";
private ObjectMapper objectMapper;
private OAuthService oAuthService;
private FacebookClient facebookClient;

@Autowired
UserAccountService userAccountService;
@Autowired
UserPhotoService userPhotoService;


public HomeController() {
     this.oAuthService = buildOAuthService(client_id, app_secret);
}
//starts the oauth by passing necessary parameters and initializes oauthservice.
private OAuthService buildOAuthService(String client_id, String app_secret){
    return new ServiceBuilder()
            .apiKey(client_id)
            .apiSecret(app_secret)
            .callback(url+"/auth/facebook/callback") //redirects the callback and must match the url in facebook settings.
            .provider(FacebookApi.class)
            .scope("email")
            .build();
}
  //login page redirects to facebook to get user details
  @RequestMapping(value="/")
  public String HomePage() {
   return "login";
  }

//link redirects to facebook for access token.
@RequestMapping(value="/auth/facebook", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public RedirectView startAuthentication(HttpSession httpSession) throws OAuthException {
    String state = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    httpSession.setAttribute(STATE, state);
    String authorizationUrl = oAuthService.getAuthorizationUrl(Token.empty())+"&"+STATE+"="+state;
    return new RedirectView(authorizationUrl);
}
//method handles the callback from facebook
@RequestMapping(value="/auth/facebook/callback")
public String callback(@RequestParam("code")String code, @RequestParam(STATE)String state, HttpSession httpsession) throws IOException
{
    //checks state parameter.
    String stateFromSession = (String)httpsession.getAttribute(STATE);
    httpsession.removeAttribute(STATE);
    if(!state.equals(stateFromSession)) { //incase of failure redirects user to login
        return "login";
    }
    //Exchanges the access token
    Token accessToken = getAccessToken(code);
   //pass token to restfb
   this.facebookClient = new DefaultFacebookClient(accessToken.getToken(), Version.VERSION_2_2);
    return "logged"; //successfully logged in.
}

//retrieves the access token
private Token getAccessToken(String code) {
    Verifier verify = new Verifier(code);
    return oAuthService.getAccessToken(Token.empty(), verify);//Token.Empty() method in scribe and handles OAuthservice for both OAuth1 and 2.
}

@RequestMapping(value="/{user-id}/attending", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
public @ResponseBody void getProfile(@PathVariable("user-id")String userId) {
    User me = facebookClient.fetchObject("me", User.class);
   userAccountService.create(me);//able to retrieve user info successfully
   userPhotoService.create(me, facebookClient); // i pass the token

    return;
}
```

The class below is a service that retrieves the photo:

```
@Repository
public class UserPhotoServiceImpl implements UserPhotoService {

@Autowired
private PhotoRepo photorepo; //extends mongorepository

public UserPhotos create(User me, FacebookClient faceboookClient){
    UserPhotos userPhotos = new UserPhotos();
    Connection<Photo> photoConnection = facebookClient.fetchConnection("me/photos", Photo.class);
    for(List<Photo> eachPhoto: photoConnection) {
        for(Photo p: eachPhoto){
            userPhotos.setPhotoId(p.getId());//storing info in userPhotos class
            userPhotos.setCountry(p.getPlace().getLocation().getCountry());
        }
    }
    System.out.println(userPhotos.getCountry());//for debugging purposes returns null and cannot retrieve any photos.
   photorepo.save(userPhotos); //trying to save to mongoDB but returns null.

    return userPhotos;
   }
} //
```

Below is my UserPhotoService class:

```
public interface UserPhotoService {
UserPhotos create(User me, FacebookClient facebookClient);
}
```

It seems token returning null or not the same token. Please, I need some help on what is wrong.

Comment: Looks like you are not asking for the necessary permission to access a user’s photos during login, only permission in your scope is `email`.

Comment: @CBroe i added the user_photo permission but still no success

Comment: Have you tried to check your access token and request on graph api explorer?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is helpful or not, but when browsing the website and downloading a photo, three header key values have to be present in addition to the URL of the photo, in order to get a download to complete. Those three key values are:

```
oh
oe
dl
```

The complete URL GET request would look something like:

```
https://thefolder.net/photos/v/t1.09/thenumericcodeofthephoto.jpg?oh=somelongalphanumericcode&oe=somemorealphanumerics&dl=1
```

My guess would be that you are missing one of the key values that needs to be passed to the server to retrieve the file(s). Rather than downloading all of the files in one chunk, have you tried downloading an individual photo by itself? I'd attempt to download a singular file first since its easier to troubleshoot, and once successful, attempt to download more files at a time.

EDIT***After looking at the documentation for restFB, I'm wondering if the reason it won't work is because the Facebook REST commands are no longer supported by Facebook and won't work. All I see for Facebook REST access has to do with graphing. It may be that you simply cannot access Facebook using the old REST interface.

Comment: @3m0I3y i have tried getting one photo but no success

Comment: It may be that the REST commands are no longer supported. I've been looking through the documentation and I don't see any valid commands for downloading via REST. I hope you find what you are looking for. Good luck.

Comment: Oh. Yeah. I found this. It does look like REST no longer works. [Facebook Developers Docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading#restapiv21)